# How to close the overlay using back button in device(iOS) , not in browser?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

Just want to close/hide the overlay(jquery) using the back button in the device

The overlay should be closed while the back button pressed on device, in safari browser

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G4j5.png)

Comment: the overlay is created using jquery

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add a [mcve]?

Comment: iOS devices don't have a back button, they have a home button. Is that what you're referring to?